# jqgrid load from multiple urls

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a page, that has jqgrid, it is fetching json from a url. I want to load data from multiple urls instead on one url, on the same grid.

How can I achieve that. The reason is, I have to display data from different sources, the ids will be unique no-matter if its from which source.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load the data which you want to place in the grid as array of items. From every source you will get an array. then you can concatinate the arrays for example with respect of [jQuery.merge](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.merge/). You will receive the full array of items. At the end you create jqGrid with `datatype: 'local'` and with the array of concatenated items as the value of the [data](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aoptions) parameter.

Comment: I did the same thing before reading your answer, thanks anyway :)

Comment: @Ali: You are welcome! The usage of `data` parameter is already the best way (of cause if you use `gridview: true` parameter which you should use almost always). jqGrid will build HTML fragment which represent *the whole* grid body at once. If you will use any other way like `addRowData`, `addJSONData` and so on the HTML data will be placed not at once so it will work slowly.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try just calling `addJSONData` multiple times?

```
var grid = $('#'+grid_id)[0];
grid.addJSONData(jsondata1); 
grid.addJSONData(jsondata2); 
grid.addJSONData(jsondata3);
```